# Placing a balloon tip at bottom left position to notify about a file download

Tags: css, css-position

I need to notify user what to do after a file was downloaded from a web page.

To do this, I am placing a balloon tooltip which I am styling this way:

```
   #infoBalloon {
        width: 100px;
        height: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 90px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
```

The problem is that the balloon appears, but when the file starts to be downloaded, the file download bottom bar is placed over the balloon tip, causing the balloon to be partially hidden.

[image]

I tried to show the balloon tip after 2 seconds when the file started to be downloaded, but it depends on the network speed so it is not an accurate solution.

When the file download bar is already shown, the balloon tip is displayed perfectly.

[image]

How can I do it to make that balloon tip to move up when the file download bar appears?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Post a [mcve] .

Comment: So this is supposed to point _to_ the download bar? What download bar, my browser does not have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way: increase bottom value by default.

```css
#infoBalloon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 90px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

Second way: Apply one class conditionally, while the file is being downloaded. Then put the `bottom` value on this applied class so it’s not overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `margin-bottom` for that:

```
   #infoBalloon {
        width: 100px;
        height: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 90px;
        bottom: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30%;
    }
```